# Passing data from HTML to PHP and back to HTML

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

So I want to write a link in id="id_input" and when I press the button name="b" I want that link to go to page2.php in the row $html->load_file(); and then the variable $slbl from page2.php to pass to page1.php in textarea name="desc_name".

I'm new at web programming and I'm learning so please explain to me if you want.
And I tried everything I could found but without success. And because that I need explanation for this example.

> page1.php

```
<html>
<body>
<?php   
include ("page2.php");
?>
<form action="page1.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div>
                <div><textarea name="desc_name" rows="7" cols="50" id="id_desc" value="<?php echo (isset($slbl))?$slbl:'';?>"></textarea></div>

                <div><input id="id_input" type="text" name="name_input" size="50">
                    <button name="b" type="button">Button</button></div>
<div>
                <div><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Publish"></div>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
...code for saving in mysql...
?>
```

> page2.php

```
<?php
        include ("simple_html_dom.php");
        // Create DOM from URL or file
        $html = new simple_html_dom();
        $html->load_file(<!--i need here url from id="id_input"--!>);
        $html = $html->find('.summary_text', 0);
        $html2 = strip_tags($html);
        $html2 = trim($html2);
        $slbl = $html2; 
?>
```

Comment: @Mr.Engineer I don't get any error I just don't know what to do next with my code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you use jquery for this purpose?

Try this :

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="page1.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div>
                <div><textarea name="desc_name" rows="7" cols="50" id="id_desc"></textarea></div>

                <div><input id="id_input" type="text" name="name_input" size="50">
                    <button name="b" class="b" type="button">Button</button></div>
<div>
                <div><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Publish"></div>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
<script>
$(".b").click(function () {
    var val = $("#id_input").val();
    $.post("page2.php",{a:val},function (data){
        $("#id_desc").val(data);
    });
});
</script>
<?php
...code for saving in mysql...
?>
```

page2.php :

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["a"])) {
        $a = $_POST["a"];
        include ("simple_html_dom.php");
        // Create DOM from URL or file
        $html = new simple_html_dom();
        $html->load_file(); //you can use $a here as per your need.
        $html = $html->find('.summary_text', 0);
        $html2 = strip_tags($html);
        $html2 = trim($html2);
        echo $slbl = $html2; 
        exit;
    }
?>
```

Comment: And what to do with this line $html->load_file(<!--i need here url from id="id_input"--!>); ? in page2.php

Comment: Working, you are my hero! Thank you very much.